# grep remove head tags

Tags: html, regex, grep

I'm trying to get only content between body tag
here is an example file

```
<html>
<head>
<tite>
Test1 
</title>
</head>
<body> 
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

I tried

```
grep "\<body\>.*\<\/body\>" index.html
```

But it just returns nothing (doing -v returns the entire thing to make sure its the right file).

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1043165

Comment: What's the exact statement you try? What's index.html? Do you meant the source of index.html?

Comment: Sorry, indentation error. I use grep "\<body\>.*\<\/body\>" index.html
 where index.html is the sample file I put up (with test1 and hello world!)

Comment: @Martijn: I think this might be a case where you actually *can* use regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `grep` for multiline pattern matching. Use [awk](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/) instead:

```
awk '/<body>/,/<\/body>/' index.html
```

Will return:

```
<body>
Hello World!
</body>
```